# Para que serve o arquivo .env no Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

1. Para que serve o arquivo `.env`?
2. No `app.php` tem `env => env('APP_ENV','production')`. O que seria esse ***production***? Qual outra `string` pode ir ali?
3. E a `var APP_ENV`? O que significa?

Answer (score 13):

No arquivo .env ficam armazenadas as configurações de ambiente do Laravel.

De acordo com a [documentação](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.2#environment-configuration):

## Configurações do Ambiente

É muito útil ter diferentes valores de configuração baseado no ambiente em que a aplicação está rodando. Por exemplo, você pode querer usar diferentes drivers de cache localmente e outro no servidor de produção. Isso é muito fácil usando as configurações baseadas em ambiente.

Para tornar isso fácil, o Laravel utiliza a Biblioteca PHP DotEnv do Vance Lucas (vlucas). Numa instalação inicial do Laravel, no diretório principal da aplicação conterá o arquivo `env.example.` Se você instalou o Laravel via Composer, esse arquivo será automaticamente copiado para `.env`. Entretanto, você pode copiar ou renomeá-lo manualmente.

Todas as variáveis listadas nesse arquivo serão carregadas a variável super global do PHP `$_ENV` quando sua aplicação receber uma requisição. Você pode usar a função utilitária env para pegar esses valores. Se você revisou os arquivos de configuração do Laravel, você deve ter percebido que muitas das opções já utilizam essa função utilitária.

Você é livre para modificar suas variáveis de ambiente como quiser, para sua aplicação local ou para seu servidor de produção. Entretanto, seu arquivo `.env` não deve ser versionado, por que cada desenvolvedor / servidor podem precisar de uma configuração diferente desse arquivo.

Se você está desenvolvendo em equipe, você pode incluir o arquivo `.env.example` e adicionar lá alguns comentários sobre a configuração do arquivo, para que cada desenvolvedor entenda claramente quais configurações eles devem fazer em seus próprios `.env` para rodar sua aplicação.

### Acessando o Ambiente da Aplicação Atual

Você pode acessar o ambiente atual da sua aplicação pelo método environmentdo facade App:

```
$environment = App::environment();
```

Você também pode passar arguementos para o método environment para verificar se o ambiente atual é o que foi passado por argumento. Você pode até passar multiplos ambientes ou fazer a chamada ao método múltiplas vezes, se necessário:

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // Aqui instruções para rodar no ambiente local
}

if (App::environment('local', 'staging')) {
    // Aqui instruções para rodar no ambiente local OU staging
}
```

Uma instancia da aplicação também pode ser acessada pela função utilitária app:

```
$environment = app()->environment();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Pra que serve o arquivo .env?

O arquivo `.env` é uma maneira mais fácil de carregar variáveis de configuração personalizadas que o seu aplicativo precisará ter.

Isso significa que você terá que modificar o arquivo fora do projeto, e todas as variáveis de ambiente serão sempre definidas não importando como você execute seu código isso se reflete até em servidores embutidos do PHP.

> O que seria esse production?

O ***production*** é o ambiente que sua aplicação se encontra, podendo também ser definido como ***local***.

> E a var APP_ENV? O que significa?

ENV vem de *Environment*, que significa Ambiente. Toda configuração criada gera uma chave com esse valor para definição do ambiente em que se encontra seu projeto.

Detalhes

- [Environment Detection & Environment Variables](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-environment-detection-and-environment-variables)
- [Configurando Environment](http://www.laravel.com.br/configurando-environment-em-laravel-5/)